# Remote Rejects Push With Commit Must Have Valid Signature

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error when doing a push

```sh
git push
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 586 bytes | 195.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6), completed with 6 local objects.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: Commits must have valid signatures.
To https://github.com/xxx-xxx-xxx
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx-xxx-xxx'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GitHub has a **branch protection setting** when enabled would **allow only commits signed with verified signatures** to be pushed to a branch. This setting is under
**Settings -> Branches -> Branch protection rules** for every repository on GitHub.

[image]

If you don't have control over the repo settings, you **would have to sign your commits** before pushing to the GitHub remote repo.

For signing your commit, if you're using a GPG key, you need to configure Git to use that with the below command (replacing `keyID` with your GPG key ID). If you don’t have a GPG key installed, you can generate one with `gpg --gen-key`.

```
git config --global user.signingkey keyID
```

You can then sign your commits by adding the `-S` flag as below

```
git commit -S -m "commitMessage"
```

You can then push your commits to the GitHub repo.

GitHub has a documentation regarding [signing commits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/signing-commits) which you can refer to. Alternatively, you can even refer to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) about signing your work. GitHub's documentation about requiring commit signing is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-required-commit-signing).