# Why does Git say that I bypassed the rule for "Commits must have valid signatures" even though my commit is signed by GNUPG?

Tags: git, github, gnupg, gpg-signature

So today I added a rule in my team's GitHub repo that every commit must have a valid signature. I installed GPG to sign my commits, but when I push my commit to the GitHub repo, it kept on saying that I bypassed that rule. But when I added the flag `--signed`, the GitHub repo does not accept it. Here is the output of when I pushed without `--signed`:

```
C:\Users\Family\Parkour>git add .

C:\Users\Family\Parkour>git ci -S -m "firstcommit"
[main fefd3e6] firstcommit
 6 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 856 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 notshowingfiles
 delete mode 100644 notshowingfiles

C:\Users\Family\Parkour>git push
Enumerating objects: 19, done.
Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1.39 KiB | 236.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (9/9), completed with 9 local objects.
remote: Bypassed rule violations for refs/heads/main:
remote:
remote: - Commits must have valid signatures.
remote:
To https://github.com/team/game.git
   67ef523..fefd3e6  main -> main
```

And here is the output of when I pushed with `--signed`

```
C:\Users\Family\Parkour>git add .
warning: in the working copy of 'notshowingfiles', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it

C:\Users\TheUser\Parkour>git ci -S -m "secondcommit"
[main 946458c] secondcommit
 9 files changed, 1695 insertions(+), 853 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 notshowingfiles
 create mode 100644 notshowingfiles

C:\Users\TheUser\Parkour>git push --signed
fatal: the receiving end does not support --signed push
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/team/game.git'
```

(removed some stuff)

Does GitHub not support GPG, or I have a mistake somewhere?

Comment: maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932155/remote-rejects-push-with-commit-must-have-valid-signature

Comment: Although it is related, I am not asking the same question as him/her. My questions are, why does Git say that I bypassed the rule for commits EVEN IF I signed them, and how do I fix "the receiving end does not support --signed push"?

Comment: GitHub doesn't support signed pushes, as the message tells you - https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23515. Are there other commits you're pushing that _aren't_ signed?

Comment: No, there aren't other commits that I'm pushing that aren't signed (sorry for late comment, really busy with other projects rn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [jornrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) already said in a comment, [a *signed push* is not supported by github](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23515).

But what you most probably enabled instead with that rule is to enforce [*signed commits*](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits). To push signed commits, you do a normal push, as you did in your first snippet.

The error message then *doesn't say your commits are not signed*, it says, the signature is *not valid*.
What this most probably refers to is a so called [*verified signature*](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification#default-statuses).

So, to enable github to *verify* your signature, you need to add the public key of your signing keypair to github. You can find good [step-by-step descriptions in their docs for each variant](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification), be it GPG, SSH or S/MIME.

Since you mentioned GPG in the tags, [here's a direct link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/adding-a-gpg-key-to-your-github-account).

Basically it's `Settings`, `Access`, `SSH and GPG keys` and add it there.