# Using personal access token on GitHub repo not working as a signature

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have been trying to work on a private repo which requires signatures to push and pull. When setting up, I received a personal access token from GitHub, and when cloning the repo using HTTPS, I was asked to insert my GitHub username and password, to which I entered my username and PAT for the password. That worked, but when I try to merge the pull request on GitHub after pushing, it says "All commits must have signatures." Any thoughts?

I have tried to use GPG configuration to sign my commits, but that was a much more complicated process. I would rather do it using the personal access token.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932155/remote-rejects-push-with-commit-must-have-valid-signature

Comment: You can't use a PAT to sign commits. The [options](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits) are GPG, SSH, and S/MIME.